# Javascript access key in text file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this call:

```
 async getData(budget) {
    const res = await fetch("/json/sample.txt");
    const data = await res.text();

    return this.setState({ data });
  }
```

And my sample.json is formatted like so:

```
{(150, 'Points'): {'0': {'name': 'Matheus', 'slug': 'matheus-galdezani',...}
```

How can I access `{'0': {'name': 'Matheus', 'slug': 'matheus-galdezani',...}` using `(150, 'Points')` as a key? Is this valid `JavaScript`?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, since keys aren't surrounded by double quotes there, nor are strings. `{(150, 'Points'):` isn't valid either - the first part of an object literal-ish in JSON must be a key, not an apparent use of the comma operator (which is allowed in JS, but not JSON)

Comment: what if  it's txt, then?

Comment: Then you should fix whatever's generating the text, since it's extremely broken at the moment. Get it to be generated in JSON instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest.

[Change]

```
[Do not use]
{(150, 'Points'): {'0': {'name': 'Matheus', 'slug': 'matheus-galdezani',...}


[Use]
{'150,Points': {'0': {'name': 'Matheus', 'slug': 'matheus-galdezani',...}
```

You can '150,Points' key.

And you can do '150,Points' to ['150', 'Points'] using javascript split

```
[Example]
const arr = '150,Points'.split(',') // ['150', 'Points'];
const num = Number(arr[0]); // 150
const str = arr[1]; // 'Points'
```